# O que é o erro Broken Pipe?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, ciência-da-computação, tcp

O que significa o erro Broken Pipe? E também o que seria um `Pipe` em computação?

Esse erro já me ocorreu várias vezes e em várias linguagens de programação até mesmo ao usar alguns programas como `ssh`. Mas eu não faço idéia do que quer dizer.

Answer (score 3):

Um *pipe*, se usar a tradução literal, seria um "cano", por onde trafegam dados, informação, etc. Ou seja, um canal isolado que protege esses dados, seja de alteração, seja para que siga um fluxo.

Um conceito um pouco mais amplo seria de *pipeline*, ou seja, um "encanamento" por onde os dados trafegam. Esse conceito é aplicado a outras áreas além da computação, como administração e vendas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguns exemplos de onde podemos usar o termo:

- A pipeline de vendas (fluxo desde que o cliente escolheu um produto até o pagamento);
- Pipeline de CI/CD (integração contínua), desde quando o desenvolvedor enviou um código, compilação, testes, aprovação, até estar em live/produção.

Em termos gerais, é um fluxo que a informação segue.

No exemplo do `ssh`, que é um comando que cria um canal de comunicação criptografada entre dois pontos, ele cria um "*pipe*" seguro para a informação trafegar, então um erro de "*broken pipe*" significa que esse canal de comunicação foi quebrado, algum problema de rede, algum dos lados parou de respoder, esgotou o tempo limite (*timeout*), etc.

Se entrar mais no conceito de rede, deve lembrar do famoso [Modelo OSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_OSI), uma modelo que propõe uma série de camadas por onde a informação deve trafegar. Cada camada do modelo por onde a informação passa seria um pipe, e todo o caminho que a informação percorre, por exemplo do momento que alguém digita "pt.stackover.com" no navegador, essa informação passa por vários componentes de *software/hardware*, até chegar a página renderizada ao navegador, seria uma grande *pipeline*.

Comment: Quando falou broken pipe eu lembrei que pipes são também uma forma de IPC (comunicação entre processos) de sistemas operacionais POSIX (usados naquelas sequências de comandos de shell em que se usa `|` para separar um comando do outro, por exemplo `ls | grep`). Nesse contexto, um erro de broken pipe poderia ser uma falha na comunicação de um processo (programa) com outro. Mas pelo que pesquisei esse erro está mais relacionado a conexão via rede (sockets) mesmo.